# What is the best practice creating IFRAME using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, iframe

What is the best practice creating an `iframe` HTML element using JavaScript?

```
 var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.setAttribute("sandbox", "")
 iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
```

I faced the question while developing Firefox plugin, but usage is quite the same as developing a web page. I do not use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can try  like [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/externalhtml.shtml):-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc() {
  iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://example.com/");
  iframe.style.width = "640px";
  iframe.style.height = "480px";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
</script>
```

Comment: No problem ;) One question though, why do you write `640+"px"` instead of `"640px"` directly?

Comment: should I use `sandbox` attribute? Other HTML5 features?

Comment: Yes you can use. The sandbox attribute enables a set of extra restrictions for the content in the inline frame. NOTE:- The sandbox attribute is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Opera.